# How to Sort the following Array Based on Timespan in AngularFire?

Tags: sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, snapshot

```
{
0
:
{associate_sales: "j72LOAjajLRbKKK0XYfHcCMghdB3", displayName: "Sneh", email: "sneh@email.com",  timespan: 1, …}
1
:
{displayName: " Sales4", email: "sales4@email.com",  timespan: 1, uid: "2e5piC6E8eO16qDDaP0qPA0LDRJ3", …}
2
:
{associate_sales: "c8kMXIkXcRgTUInPbdhL5oinbzv2", displayName: " client11", email: "client11@email.com", timespan: 12, …}
3
:
{associate_sales: "j72LOAjajLRbKKK0XYfHcCMghdB3", displayName: "Client1", email: "client1@email.com", timespan: 1522320931451, …} }
```

This is the response I fetch in console. how to fetch this result according to timespan asceding or descending order. 
I am using following method but its not working

```
 this.databaseObj2.orderByChild('timespan').once('value', (snapshot) => {
// code
});
```

Please help. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First push data into the array as json object.

```
let temp_array = [];
this.databaseObj2.orderByChild('timespan').once('value', (snapshot) => {
   let result = snapshot.val();
   for(let k in result){
      temp_array.push({
         id : k, // this "K" gives the id of you object
         timespan : result[k].timespan,
         display_name : result[k].displayName,
         //rest of data 
      })
   }
});

temp_array.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.timespan) - parseFloat(a.timespan));
```

Comment: happy to helped you ;)